# Building android apk with ant under MacOS X and "Application not installed"

Tags: android, macos, bash, ant

I have a bash script that basically calls ant to compile a Android application source tree, and then uses adb to install and start the application on a connected android device.

The bash script has many options, but it basically edits AndroidManifest.xml and strings.xml to change the package and the app name, then issues "android update project ." and finally "ant release". Here is the relevant snippet:

```
if [ "$NEWPACKAGENAME" != "" ] ; then
  echo >> AndroidManifest.xml # the loop below looses the last line, 
                              # so we ensure that's a useless line
  cat AndroidManifest.xml | 
    ( while read ROW ; do
        IS_PACKAGE_ROW=`echo $ROW | grep 'package=' | wc -l` ;
        if [ $IS_PACKAGE_ROW -gt 0 ] ; then
          echo "  package=\"$NEWPACKAGENAME\"" >> AndroidManifest-np.xml
        else
          echo "$ROW" >> AndroidManifest-np.xml
        fi ;
      done
    )
  mv AndroidManifest-np.xml AndroidManifest.xml
fi

if [ "$APPNAME" != "" ] ; then
  echo >> res/values/strings.xml # the loop below looses the last line, 
                                 # so we ensure that's a useless line
  cat res/values/strings.xml |
    ( while read ROW ; do
        IS_NAME_ROW=`echo $ROW | grep '<string name="app_name">' | wc -l` ;
        if [ $IS_NAME_ROW -gt 0 ] ; then
          echo "<string name=\"app_name\">$APPNAME</string>" >> res/values/strings-nn.xml
        else
          echo "$ROW" >> res/values/strings-nn.xml
        fi ;
      done
    )
  mv res/values/strings-nn.xml res/values/strings.xml
fi

rm -f bin/*.ap_* bin/*.apk*

$ANDROID update project -p .

$ANT release
```

The script works great under GNU/Linux, it creates the apk file, it installs the file via adb, and the same apk file can be installed manually on the device by copying or downloading it to the device (Unknown sources in developers options obviously already active).

However under MacOS X it has a problem: the resulting apk file works only if installed via "adb install" (run by the script itself or by hand). If I try to manually copy or download the apk file to a Android device, I mean the apk file generated by the script when run under MacOSX, the device asks usual confirmations but then says "Application not installed".

I've already read a few questions about the "Application not installed" problem, the replies seem to point in the AndroidManifest.xml direction (duplicate activity and the like) but I fail to understand how that can be the problem in my case, since the script is just the same that works under Linux and since it does work also under MacOS X when issuing the "adb install" command itself (so the apk has to be valid).

Other things already tried/verified:

- removing the app from the device before trying to install the new
  version
- the signing key is always the same and not the debug one
  (however the device complains earlier in case I use different
  signatures)
- downloading the apk from http or as mail attachment
- dancing around the tablet with ancestral movements while trying to install...

The 4th worked once (to my surprise). But just once, then never again. I don't know what I did different that time, ancestral dances apart. Ah yes, I had removed completely unrelated applications before installing it... removed a number of them. Needless to say, removing unrelated applications didn't help other times. Besides I never reinstalled them again...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. My script is creating three APK files: myapp.apk, signed-myapp.apk and signed-aligned-myapp.apk, the last one being the correct one to install.

For a number of reasons, the file that was being used, only when running under MacOS X, was myapp.apk instead (but not when copying it through adb).

That gives us a new reason why you can receive the "Application non installed" message without further details: it also happens when the apk is not signed at all.